# SQL statement error "Must declare the scalar variable @t_p "

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

I want to add a few records to my database, but I always get this annoying error:

> Must declare the scalar variable @t_p

the given answers on this error here at stackoverflow could not help me to fix the problem.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_typ (name, [t-pass], [t-agg], [l-pass], [l-agg], b_typ, alter, [v-str], str, nor, wea, be_msg) VALUES (@sname, @t_p, @t_a, @l_p, @l_a, @btype, @alt, @v_s, @s, @n, @w, @b) ";

 using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query,con))
 {
     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = S_Name.Substring(4);
     string resultString = Regex.Match(S_Name, @"\d+").Value;
     int tb_absender = Int32.Parse(resultString) + 1;

     for (int i = 0; i <= Spieler_Daten.Count; i += 5 )
     {
         if (Spieler_Daten.Count < i)
         {
             if (Spieler_Daten[i] == tb_absender)
             {
                 if (Spieler_Daten[i + 1] == 1)
                 {
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@t_p", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@t_a", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@l_p", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@l_a", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
                 }

                 if (Spieler_Daten[i + 2] == 2)
                 {
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@btype", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = "viel";
                 }

                 if (Spieler_Daten[i + 3] == 1)
                 {
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@alt", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
                 }

                 if (Spieler_Daten[i + 3] == 0)
                 {
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@alt", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
                 }

                 if (Spieler_Daten[i + 4] == 1)//Steht für sehr stark
                 {
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@v_s", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@s", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@w", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
                 }

                 if (Spieler_Bemerkung.Contains(tb_absender.ToString()))
                 {
                     int position_bemerkung = Spieler_Bemerkung.IndexOf(tb_absender.ToString()) + 1;
                     cmd2.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Spieler_Bemerkung.ElementAt(position_bemerkung);
                 }
            }
        }
        else
        { 
             break; 
        }
    }

    try
    {
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Erfolgreich hinzugefügt: " + Spieler );
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your SQL always makes reference to `@t_p` yet you have `if` conditions that add that SQL parameter only in certain situations.  In those other cases, it will fail since the parameter will not be defined.

Comment: You should **define** and add your parameter definitions to `cmd2` *once and before* the `for` loop - only set the **values** of your parameters inside the `for` loop!

Comment: Spieler_Daten.Count will never be less than i

Comment: This is not the full code, there are other if conditions and one of it will always be true, so the Parameter will always be defined!

Comment: So show code that will be executed, not code that will never be executed.

Comment: it is the same code only the value changes, there is no need to show it ;)

Comment: Actually, one of the conditions is not always true otherwise you would not be getting the error. Either that or one of the conditions is not setting the @t_p parameter. Take a bite of humble pie and look more closely.

Comment: When you got this error while you were stepping through the code with the debugger, watching the value of @t_p, what did you see?